# Presenting MFMessageComposeViewController broken in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, modalviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

My app presents a MFMessageComposeViewController modally. It was working perfectly fine in iOS 5 (both on the simulator and on the device). After I upgraded my iPhone to 6, it simply doesn’t work anymore. The app freezes for like 10 seconds, then this message appears in the debugger

"Remote compose controller timed out (YES)!"

And the modal view does not show up.
I searched extensively on stackoverflow and on the web, and couldn’t find any solution.
As a final resort, I downloaded and ran the sample code of apple, "MessageComposer" and, alas, even in apple code it does not work on iOS 6.
I`m completely clueless and have spent hours on this... Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't have an answer to why that was happening yet, but I realized that it happens only in the iPhone 5. And sometimes doesn't happen at all. Probably another of those iOS 6 bugs (hopefully to be solved in iOS 6.1)

Comment: Agreed. Helping another user related to a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676500/ios-6-uiactivityviewcontroller-timeout-bug/13692785#13692785, we concluded that the problem was a specific device and when he rebooted the device, the problem disappeared. It's not very assuring to have a crash that cannot be consistently reproduced. (And it's hard to fix if you cannot reproduce it.)

Comment: It might be worthy of a https://bugreport.apple.com ...